# My helmet durability is 0?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I made a helmet with thorns 1000 for myself, (using commands) and I thought I could have a helmet with a durability of 3 with thorns 1000 as a prize. I wore my helmet, (The one with 3) and I got attacked by a spider. I was wearing my helm, and not it has a red 0, but no damage bar. Glitch? Or is it just one more hit and it'll go?

Comment: What command did you use to give yourself the helmet?

Comment: It sounds like you've set your durability very low, and % durability is less than is required for 1 section/pixel to be coloured in.

Answer (score 3):

The red 0 means you have given yourself an item stack of 0 items, which minecraft does not like. Double check the parameters of where you have gotten the item from to make sure you are not giving yourself 0 items.